# What am I missing about creating ISOs using pycdlib?

Tags: python-3.x

My NAS backs up my wife's and my iPhone pictures and videos. I have a separate Debian box I use to rsync those files to and I am trying to develop a Python script to take those folders, organize them by whether they are photos or videos, whether they are from me or my wife and then generate ISOs that I can just burn to Blurays and/or DVDs at will. I developed my Python3 script on my Windows laptop and I was able to make ISOs using pycdlib in UDF format. When the script finished, I'd open up the ISO and see my files organized as I wanted them. When I moved to my Debian box, the ISOs were still created and the directories in the ISOs are created but no files appear to be added. The size of the ISO is much too small and you can't see any pictures or video files in the ISO when you mount it to check. I tried switching to Rock Ridge with the same results, then Joliet then a combination of Rock Ridge and Joliet and still no love.

What am I missing? I am posting the loop that goes through files and [a link to the full script for the curious.](https://github.com/dietolead/Python_Scripts/blob/master/backupprocess.py)

```
bluray_max = 23000000000
dvd_max = 4617000000
max_iso_size = dvd_max
current_iso = 1
current_total_size = 0

iso_photo = pycdlib.PyCdlib()
iso_photo.new(joliet=True, rock_ridge="1.09")

for root, dirnames, filenames in walk(path.join(tmp_dir, "photos")):
    for directory in dirnames:
        direct = "/" + directory.upper()
        iso_photo.add_directory(
            direct,
            joliet_path=f'/{directory}',
            rr_name=directory)
    for file in filenames:
        if r"photos\Gage" in root:
            iso_photo.add_file(
                path.join(root, file),
                f'/GAGE/{file};3',
                joliet_path=f'/Gage/{file}',
                rr_name=file)
        elif r"photos\Callen" in root:
            iso_photo.add_file(
                path.join(root, file),
                f'/CALLEN/{file};3',
                joliet_path=f'/Callen/{file}',
                rr_name=file)
        current_total_size += path.getsize(path.join(root, file))
        if current_total_size >= max_iso_size:
            iso_photo.write(path.join(
                iso_location,
                "photos_" + str(current_iso) + ".iso"))
            iso_photo.close()
            current_total_size = 0
            current_iso += 1
            iso_photo = pycdlib.PyCdlib()
            iso_photo.new(joliet=True, rock_ridge="1.09")
            for root, dirnames in walk(path.join(tmp_dir, "photos")):
                for directory in dirnames:
                    direct = "/" + directory.upper()
                    iso_photo.add_directory(
                        direct,
                        joliet_path=f'/{directory}',
                        rr_name=directory)
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No, the script completes successfully whether on Windows or Debian. When testing the script on Debian, I run it as root. My intention once I understand what I'm doing wrong is to setup a service account to run the script that'll have the file rights it needs.